# Restangular - Nested Resources

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

What is the best practices when dealing with nested resources with restangular?
i.e.

```
Restangular.one("accounts", 1).one("projects", 1).get().then(function (project) {
project.getList("proofs").then(function(proofs){
    project.proofs = proofs;
    _.each(proofs, function(proof){
        proof.comments = proof.getList("comments");
    });
});
$scope.project = project;
```

});

This would allow me to access each inside the view nicely.

```
<li ng-repeat="proof in project.proofs">Total: {{proof.comments.length}}</li>
```

If I then want to make a update to the project, it would then send EVERYTHING to the projects REST endpoint (including all proofs, and all proofs.comments).

```
project.name = 'New Name!';
project.put();
```

This makes me think that I must be implementing something wrong, and there muse be a better way of dealing with it?

Short of defining everything straight to individual $scope's with something like this (not tested)?
i.e.

```
Restangular.one("accounts", 1).one("projects", 1).get().then(function (project) {
project.getList("proofs").then(function(proofs){
    $scope.projectProofs = proofs;
    _.each(proofs, function(proof){  
      $scope.proofComments[proof.id].push(proof.getList("comments"));
    });
});
$scope.project = project;
```

});

What is the suggested best practice for this?

Comment: Two things that might be helpful: 1) put the requests themselves in a service and expose only a method that will return a promise. This way you can do your promise chaining/grouping within a service so you only have to resolve the "final" promise in your controller. 2) use a config service to define constants to be able to easily configure the actually used URLs throughout your project.

Comment: 3) have you looked at $q.all to resolve everything :)?

Comment: @mgonto do you know what is going on here (with the POST)? I'm interested in this as well, as I'm currently evaluating using restangular in my app. And I have tons of nested scenarios like this.

Comment: which version of Restangular are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options: write a custom PUT method or delete the property from the object

## Option #1: write a custom PUT method

The default method for putting an element will submit *all* the parameters that are set.

You can see this in the Restangular source code where every Resource is initialized with a default set of methods that accept all parameters and do not do *any* filtering to remove parameters.

You can create a custom method that strips the 'proofs' property from the object or only selects certain fields to PUT in the request.

## Option #2: delete the property from the object.

Before you `put()` your project, you can do something like this:

```
/* ... code to get the project object and the nested proof objects ... */

project.name = 'New Name!';

delete project.proofs;
project.put();
```

The delete keyword will remove the property from the object. Then when you call `put()` the project object will no longer have the the nested resource in it. [You can read more about the delete keyword here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

You can print out the object at the console to see exactly what you're putting to the server:

```
console.log(project);
```

Answer (score 0):

If only modify one field, you can use `element.patch` with a param, like this:

```
// get project...

update = function(field, value){
  project.patch({ field, value });
}
```

In addition, most of the time your field's value was changed through `<input ng-model="project.FIELD_NAME"/>`, so you can reuse it:

In your controller:

```
// get project...

$scope.update = function(field){
  payload = {};
  payload[field] = $scope.project[field];
  project.patch(payload);
}
```

In your template

```
<!-- Use submit button or ng-blur... -->
<input ng-model="project.FIELD_NAME" />
```